# Filter hasOne ofMany query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to use Laravel's `hasOne(Model::class)->ofMany('relationship')` but I would also like to additionally filter the considered results.

My problem in a bit more detail:

I have these two simplified tables that I use in a WYSIWYG style authoring tool:

> documents: `id (PK),...`
>
> document revisions table:
> `id (PK),document_id (FK),revision_id,is_autosave,...`

In the revisions table the combination `document_id, revision_id, is_autosave` is unique meaning that a document can have the same revision_id for an autosaved and a manually saved revision.

I am trying to relate the latest manually saved revision with the document model using the code below:

```
public function mainRevision() {
   return $this->hasOne(DocumentRevision::class)
      ->where('autosave', false)
      ->ofMany('revision_id', 'max');
}
```

I can call the above e.g. like `Documents::with('mainRevision')->where(...)->get()`.
The intention is to eager-load the latest manual revision and only the latest manual revision for all matched document rows.

However this generates the following query:

```sql
select
    `document_revisions`.*
from
    `document_revisions` inner join (
        select
            max(`document_revisions`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`,
            min(`document_revisions`.`revision_id`) as `revision_id_aggregate`,
            `document_revisions`.`document_id`
        from
            `document_revisions`
                inner join (
                    select max(`document_revisions`.`revision_id`) as `revision_id_aggregate`,`document_revisions`.`document_id`
                    from `document_revisions` 
                    where `document_revisions`.`document_id` in (`<list of matched ids from the 1st query>`)
                group by
                    `document_revisions`.`document_id`
            ) as `mainVersion`
            on `mainVersion`.`revision_id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`revision_id` and `mainVersion`.`document_id` = `document_revisions`.`document_id`
        group by `document_revisions`.`document_id`) as `mainVersion` 
    on `mainVersion`.`id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`id`
        and `mainVersion`.`revision_id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`revision_id`
        and `mainVersion`.`document_id` = `document_revisions`.`document_id`
where
    `autosave` = 0
```

While I can see the intention here, there is a problem in that the `where autosave=0` is added outside the joined table. This results in the situation where if the latest revision_id happens to only correspond to an autosave, then it is not picked up.

I would ideally like the query to be like:

```sql
select
    `document_revisions`.*
from
    `document_revisions` inner join (
        select
            max(`document_revisions`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`,
            min(`document_revisions`.`revision_id`) as `revision_id_aggregate`,
            `document_revisions`.`document_id`
        from
            `document_revisions`
                inner join (
                    select max(`document_revisions`.`revision_id`) as `revision_id_aggregate`,`document_revisions`.`document_id`
                    from `document_revisions` 
                    where `autosave` = 0 --<<----------- change here
                     and `document_revisions`.`document_id` in (`<list of matched ids from the 1st query>`) 
                group by
                    `document_revisions`.`document_id`
            ) as `mainVersion`
            on `mainVersion`.`revision_id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`revision_id` and `mainVersion`.`document_id` = `document_revisions`.`document_id`
        group by `document_revisions`.`document_id`) as `mainVersion` 
    on `mainVersion`.`id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`id`
        and `mainVersion`.`revision_id_aggregate` = `document_revisions`.`revision_id`
        and `mainVersion`.`document_id` = `document_revisions`.`document_id`
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#advanced-has-one-of-many-relationships), you can add conditions to the `ofMany()` query by passing a closure as the second parameter. This also requires the aggregate columns to be passed in the first parameter using the array notation. Example below:

```
public function mainRevision() {
    return $this->hasOne(DocumentRevision::class)
        ->ofMany([
            'revision_id' => 'max'
        ], function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('autosave', false);
        });
}
```

---

Unrelated, but Laravel also has [another way](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#converting-many-relationships-to-has-one-relationships) of defining "one of many" you may prefer, by converting the existing `hasMany()` relationship to a `hasOne()`. There is no difference between this and what you have, just a preference of style. Assuming you have `hasMany()` relationship defined as `documentRevisions()`, you can call the `one()` method on it to convert it to a `hasOne()` relationship:

```
public function mainRevision() {
    return $this->documentRevisions()
        ->one()
        ->ofMany([
            'revision_id' => 'max'
        ], function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('autosave', false);
        });
}
```